# My int timestamp to Date isn't running

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, timestamp

I'm trying to make a method that return the Date of a timestamp and the conversion isn't running correctly (Date doesn't take the whole value ):

```
String stringDate = "" + operationDate; // operationDate is my timestamp : 1235437200
Long date = Long.valueOf(stringDate); // date worth 1235437200
Date now = new Date(date); // date show me the date of 1235437 (not 1235437200)
```

How can I make those lines work? I'm not Java specialist but the princip works!

Thanks to read / help me :-)

**EDIT**

When I show now (the final date), it gives me Thu Jan 15 08:10:37 CET 1970, and that date is 1235473 in timestamp... and I gave her 12354737200 thanks to the date (Long) value

My import files are

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.*;
```

**EDIT 2 :**

```
public String getHumanDate(){
    String stringDate = "" + operationDate;
    System.out.println("stringDate => " + stringDate);

    Long date = Long.valueOf(stringDate);
    System.out.println("date => " + date );

    Date now = new Date(date);
    System.out.println("now => " + now );

    System.out.println("now.toString => " + now.toString());
    return now.toString();
}
```

give me

```
INFO: stringDate => 1325437200
INFO: date => 1325437200
INFO: now => Fri Jan 16 09:10:37 CET 1970
INFO: now.toString => Fri Jan 16 09:10:37 CET 1970
```

Comment: Sorry, your question is very unclear.  What is `1235437200`? Is it milliseconds since the epoch? Something else?

Comment: Are you sure you have the right Date imported? Works for me.

Comment: @Jim : this is the timestamp in the variable "operationTime".

Comment: @svachalek : Thanks . please chek my edit

Comment: It is still not clear.  Please show on separate lines the output you are getting and the output you expect, along with the code that produces that output.

Comment: @JimG : I hope it will be with my last edit ;-)

Comment: What are expecting the result be?

Comment: the timestamp of 1235437200, so 24th of february 2009 at 2h00:00 !!! (date of the "1235437200" timestamp )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date object expects milliseconds instead of a unix timestamp, so you need to multiply by 1000.

```
Date now = new Date((long)date * 1000);  
System.out.println("now => " + now );
```

Comment: Thanks, but why does we have to *1000 ? Do I make something wrong?

Comment: @clement the unix timestamp is the quantity of seconds since Jan 01 1970. So, to transform seconds in milliseconds you multiply by 1000 :)